# Use Jupyterhub+DockerSpawner+all-spark-notebook with the existing spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub, jupyter-scala

I set up JupyterHub + DockerSpawner + all-spark-notebook in one machine, and I have an existing spark cluster.

I can log in and start server, however how to make the notebook(Toree) visit the existing spark cluster?

I googled and found someone extended all-spark-notebook docker image and reinstall Toree.

`https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/wiki/Docker-Recipes#use-jupyterall-spark-notebooks-with-an-existing-sparkyarn-cluster`

There are any easier ways to achieve the goal? Can DockerSpawner accept any arguments which could be transferred to Toree kernel?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue.
Have connected my jupyterhub to a remote spark cluster.

Here are the steps - 
1. Login to all-spark-notebook in my case through docker. 
2. You will find spark installed in /usr/local/spark
3. There you will have to change the conf/spark-env.sh and spark-defaults.conf to point to your cluster master

**Update for connecting to spark on network**

For docker container to connect to spark it must be connected in host mode to the network -

```
c.DockerSpawner.extra_host_config = { 'network_mode': 'host' }

c.DockerSpawner.use_internal_ip = True 

c.DockerSpawner.network_name = 'host'
```

This will cause issue when multiple containers try to start as all can't run on host mode. To overcome this add these lines to config -

```
from jupyterhub.utils import random_port
from tornado import gen

class custom_spawner(DockerSpawner):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get_ip_and_port(self):
        return self.container_ip, self.container_port

    @gen.coroutine
    def start(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.container_port = random_port()
        spawn_cmd = "sh /srv/singleuser/singleuser.sh --port={}".format(self.container_port)
        self.extra_create_kwargs.update({"command": spawn_cmd})

        # start the container
        ret = yield DockerSpawner.start(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return ret
```

Comment: my spark cluster sits in the same network as jupyterhub host, which means docker container(with internal network on jupyterhub host) cant' access to the network

Comment: You should make sure to also yield in the `get_ip_and_port`-function, you'll get an error about Futures otherwise in the recent versions of Jupyter Hub.